# How to include files dll/lib files on visual studio

Tags: c++, qt4

I have a project in C++ and has many includes like:

```
#include <QtCore/QString>
#include <QtCore/QCoreApplication>
#include <QtCore/QPointer>
```

I have a directory named as libs with this files:

```
QtCore4.def
QtCore4.dll
QtCore4.dump
QtCore4.exp
QtCore4.lib
```

Compiler error:

```
Cannot open include file: 'QtCore/QString': No such file or directory
```

How to solve/add this references?

Many thanks!

**EDIT**

I'm using Visual Studio 2015

Answer (score 0):

In the Solution Explorer window, right click on your project, select "Properties".

In the "Property Pages Window", in the left pane,  click on "C/C++".

In the "Additional Include Directories" item, append the name of the directory that *contains the Qt header files*.

You will need the header files because they tell the compiler the syntax of the functions in the libraries.

*Note: These directions are for Visual Studio 2010, YMMV for other versions.*

Comment: Is not possible with only this files?

Comment: And to add the library files: In the "Property Pages Window", in the left pane, click "Linker" - "General". In the right pane add your lib directory to "Additional library directories". Then, under "Linker" - "Input", add the library file names to "Additional dependencies". Also for VS2010.